# Windows Store App: Programatically access control from style in ListView

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm using a custom style on my ListView control. When the user clicks an item in the ListView I start downloading a file, id like to update a progress bar on that particular ListViewItem. Here is the style I'm using:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UpdatesListViewItemTemplate">
    <Grid Height="80">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="5,0,10,5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewTitleTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0, 2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewDetailTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0, 2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewDetailTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0, 2"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5, 0" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here are some things I have tried:

- Binding a property called DownloadProgress to the Value property of the progress bar. Is there a way I can update a specific ListViewItem so it re-gets the Binding value?
- Trying to Access the ListViewItem from the sender object that gets passed into the ItemClick method. I couldn't find any properties/methods that return a ListViewItem.

I'm all out of ideas. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewModel` for each item in your `ListView`. So instead of `ObservableCollection<Model>`, make it `ObservableCollection<DownloadableContentViewModel<Model>>`.

Then, in this `ViewModel`, put values for the `ProgressBar`, such as whether or not the `ProgressBar` should be shown and what the value should be. Expose your `Model` via something like a `WrappedItem` property.

Your `Bindings` will change to `Text="{Binding WrappedItem.Name}"`, but will otherwise work the same way.

Also, you should put a `Command` inside of your `Wrapper` `ViewModel` which starts the download and does that logic. You can then bind it to a button inside of your `ListViewItem`.

Hope this helps, happy coding!